# Ohms law and a resistor

Tags: resistors, amperage, ohms-law

I've recently just learned from the Internet that a resistor  reduce current. But when I measured the amps from the power supple to the resistor in series and then measured again from resistor to an LED. I did not see any amperage dropped, only voltage. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: The internet is a tricky place.  Since your resistor and led form a series circuit.  The current in must be the current out.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat sorry I don't really understand.. my multimeter is measured between the power supply to the resistor and from the resistor to the LED. The circuit was not connected

Comment: Was the LED ON?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat it was not on when powered, I connected the multimeter from one end of the power supple to the resistor(it was on showing the amount of amp) and then measured once more from resistor to LED . Then the led lit up

Comment: Your meter completed the circuit.   What size is the resistor?  What voltage is being applied?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat 9V and 1K ohm resistor. Was the difference to small to see? Cause I directly connect it to a 9V and my LED burnout.

Comment: Your 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor is too big.  If a RED LED approx 2Volt.  It would give you 7mA.  Something like 360\$\Omega\$ would be typical giving 20mA.

Comment: "A resistor reduces current" means the current goes down after you put the resistor in the circuit. It doesn't mean the current goes down after the current goes through the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The resistor decreases the current in the circuit as a whole.

The current is the same everywhere in a simple looping circuit. If you add more resistance that current reduces.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBAyYv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>